# No ingress address on minikube Kubernetes cluster with nginx ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I've got the following:

**ingress.yaml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: abcxyz
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: abcxyz
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /a/
        backend:
          serviceName: service-a
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /b/
        backend:
          serviceName: service-b
          servicePort: 80
```

Output of `kubectl describe ingress abcxyz`:

```
Name:             abcxyz
Namespace:        default
Address:          
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<none>)
Rules:
  Host    Path  Backends
  ----    ----  --------
  abcxyz  
          /a/   service-a:80 (<none>)
          /b/   service-b:80 (<none>)
Annotations:
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age                From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----               ----                      -------
  Normal  CREATE  16m                nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/abcxyz
  Normal  UPDATE  12m (x2 over 15m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/abcxyz
```

Why is the address empty? I've installed the 'nginx ingress controller' through helm using `helm install stable/nginx-ingress` - and all of it's pods relevent seem to be running fine.

How can I provide access to the ingress?

Comment: Does the hostname abcxyz resolve to an actual ip adress?

Comment: No it does not, to what IP should it point to?

Comment: To the static ip of the nginx-ingress-controller. It should be a service with type LoadBalancer. So the hostname should point to the front of your loadbalancer.

Comment: Because it is minikube point a hostname to your minikube cluster if you are on a nix system add an entry into /etc/hosts.

Answer (score 11):

The solution for me was:

```
minikube addons enable ingress
```

Answer (score 2):

Type

```
minikube ip
```

to retrieve the master IP. for example:

```
bash-3.2$ minikube ip
192.168.1.100
```

The command that provides information about the kubernetes cluster is:

```
bash-3.2$ kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://192.168.1.100:8443
KubeDNS is running at https://192.168.1.100:8443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
```

You can test the ingress controller from the host machine using `curl`:

```
bash-3.2$ curl http://192.168.1.100:80
default backend - 404
```

Finally, add a host entry to be able to use a name to refer to the cluster IP address

In `/etc/hosts` add:

```
192.168.1.100   abcxyz
```

Comment: if  i dont have a host and am hosted on a ec2 instance how can i access the ingress with public IP

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a bug in `https://helm.nginx.com/stable` that makes it not bind to the Address in minikube.

The solution that worked for me was to instead use `https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx`
The installation instructions for the kubernetes version of NGINX ingress are here: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/, but here's the gist:

## Helm

```sh
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
helm repo update

helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx
```

## Minikube

```sh
minikube addons enable ingress
```

## microk8s

```sh
microk8s enable ingress
```

Also to note, the ["bare metal"](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.47.0/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/deploy.yaml) [installation instructions](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#bare-metal) use a NodePort.  But most IaaS providers have their own way of assigning IPs, so they have specific [instructions](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/) for each provider.

```
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.33.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.47.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: https
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
```