# Kubernetes - Ingress with Minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-ingress

I am learning kubernetes by playing with minikube.

This is my pod deployment file which is fine.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: web
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: myapp
          image: myid/myimage
```

I am exposing the above pods using NodePort. I am able to access using minikube IP at port 30002.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-ip-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  externalIPs:
  - 192.168.99.100
  selector:
    component: web
  ports:
    - port: 3000
      nodePort: 30002
      targetPort: 8080
```

Now i would like to use ingress to access the application at port 80 which will forward the request the ip-service at port 3000. It does NOT work

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: my-ip-service
    servicePort: 3000
```

If i try to access to ingress, address is blank.

```
NAME           HOSTS   ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
test-ingress   *                 80      41m
```

How to use ingress with minikube? Or how to bind the minikube ip with ingress service - so that the app can be exposed outside without using nodeport

Comment: Please check if this question is related to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51243717/no-ingress-address-on-minikube-kubernetes-cluster-with-nginx-ingress-controller

Comment: Thanks Mr.Seth, I saw that answer already. it did not work. I did add an entry in the /etc/hosts -

Comment: @SethDifley , Thanks Seth, as you had mentioned, k8s seems to work only with some kind of external load balancers if we need to use ingress. https://blog.getambassador.io/kubernetes-ingress-nodeport-load-balancers-and-ingress-controllers-6e29f1c44f2d.   I am not sure why you deleted your answer

Comment: This solution works:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58561682/minikube-with-ingress-example-not-working/73735009?noredirect=1#comment136280333_73735009

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get your minikube node's IP address with:

```
minikube ip
```

The ingress' IP address will not populate in minikube because minikube lacks a load balancer. If you'd like something that behaves like a load balancer for your minikube cluster, https://github.com/knative/serving/blob/master/docs/creating-a-kubernetes-cluster.md#loadbalancer-support-in-minikube suggests running the following commands to patch your cluster:

```
sudo ip route add $(cat ~/.minikube/profiles/minikube/config.json | jq -r ".KubernetesConfig.ServiceCIDR") via $(minikube ip)
kubectl run minikube-lb-patch --replicas=1 --image=elsonrodriguez/minikube-lb-patch:0.1 --namespace=kube-system
```

Comment: thanks for your time. it does not answer the question. i know how to get minkube ip. my question is how to use ingress to expose the application instead of nodeport

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 4):

I think you are missing the ingress controller resource on minikube itself. There are many possible ways to create an ingress-controller resource on K8s , but i think for you the best way to start on minikube is to follow [this](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#minikube) documentation.

Don't forget to read about [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) in general once you get this working.