# Minikube with ingress example not working

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-ingress

I'm trying to get an ingress controller working in Minikube and am following the steps in the K8s documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/), but am seeing a different result in that the IP address for the ingress controller is different than that for Minikube (the example seems to indicate they should be the same):

```sh
$ kubectl get ingress
NAME              HOSTS              ADDRESS     PORTS   AGE
example-ingress   hello-world.info   10.0.2.15   80      12m

$ minikube ip
192.168.99.101
```

When I try to connect to the Minikube IP address (using the address directly vs. adding it to my local hosts file), I'm getting a "Not found" response from NGINX:

```sh
$ curl http://`minikube ip`/
<html>
    <head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
    <body>
        <center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
        <hr><center>openresty/1.15.8.1</center>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I try to connect to the IP address associated with the ingress controller, it just hangs.

Should I expect the addresses to be the same as the K8s doc indicates?

Some additional information:

```
$ kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME       STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION   INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE              KERNEL-VERSION   CONTAINER-RUNTIME
minikube   Ready    master   2d23h   v1.16.0   10.0.2.15     <none>        Buildroot 2018.05.3   4.15.0           docker://18.9.9

$ kubectl get ingresses example-ingress -o yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{"nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target":"/$1"},"name":"example-ingress","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"rules":[{"host":"hello-world.info","http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"serviceName":"web","servicePort":8080},"path":"/"}]}}]}}
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
  creationTimestamp: "2019-10-28T15:36:57Z"
  generation: 1
  name: example-ingress
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "25609"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/ingresses/example-ingress
  uid: 5e96c378-fbb1-4e8f-9738-3693cbce7d9b
spec:
  rules:
  - host: hello-world.info
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: web
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 10.0.2.15
```

Comment: Have you added the NodePort along with `minikube ip`?  something like, `http://minikubeIP:port/`

Comment: @KamolHasan, doing this worked:

`$ kubectl get service web
NAME   TYPE       CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
web    NodePort   10.107.6.230   <none>        8080:31349/TCP   77m

$ minikube ip
192.168.99.101

$ curl http://192.168.99.101:31349
Hello, world!
Version: 1.0.0
Hostname: web-9bbd7b488-bd2wm`

But I have to admit that I don't understand.  If my ingress controller is configured for a different IP:port why doesn't that work?

Comment: Please, send me the output of these commands:  
`$ kubectl get nodes -o wide`  
`$ kubectl get ingresses example-ingress -o yaml`  
You are running this minikube on top of a Bare Metal machine? Linux, Windows, Mac Os? If you are running in the cloud, in which provider?

Comment: @PjoterS, I'm running this on macOS 10.14.6 with minikube v1.5.0.  The output from the first command you recommended:

`minikube   Ready    master   2d22h   v1.16.0   10.0.2.15     <none>        Buildroot 2018.05.3   4.15.0           docker://18.9.9`

Not sure how best to provide the output from the second in a comment post here.  Suggestions?

Comment: @ShawnC as OP you can always edit your question with proper formatting.

Comment: @PjoterS, updated the OP as suggested.  To clarify, when following the example steps in the K8s docs, when creating the [ingress resource] (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/#create-an-ingress-resource), the doc seems to indicate the IP address of the ingress resource should be the same as Minikube, but that's not what I'm seeing (and why I assume I'm missing some fundamental point).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've reproduced your scenario in a Linux environment (on GCP) and I also have different IPs:

```
user@bf:~$ minikube ip
192.168.39.144

user@bf:~$ kubectl get ingresses
NAME              HOSTS   ADDRESS           PORTS   AGE
example-ingress   *       192.168.122.173   80      30m
```

Your problem is not related to the fact you have different IPs. The guide instructs us to create an ingress with the following rule:

```
spec:
  rules:
  - host: hello-world.info
```

This rule is telling the ingress service that a DNS record with `hello-world.info` name is expected.
If you follow the guide a bit further, it instructs you to create an entry on your hosts file pointing to your ingress IP or Minikube IP.

> **Note:** If you are running Minikube locally, use `minikube ip` to get the external IP. The IP address displayed within the ingress list
> will be the internal IP.
> *Source:* [Set up Ingress on Minikube with the NGINX Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/)

*(if you want to curl the IP instead of DNS name, you need to remove the host rule from your ingress)*

It should look like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
     paths:
     - path: /
       backend:
         serviceName: web
         servicePort: 8080
```

Apply your changes:

```
user@bf:~$ kubectl apply -f example-ingress.yaml
```

And curl the IP using -Lk options to surpass problems related to secure connections.

```
user@bf:~$ curl -Lk 192.168.39.144
Hello, world!
Version: 1.0.0
Hostname: web-9bbd7b488-l5gc9
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this came about, but now I'm getting the same IP address from `minikube ip` and `kubectl get ingress`.  So updating /etc/hosts with this now correctly reaches the pod with `curl hello-world.info`.  No idea why, but I'm going to try with the "real" deployment I'm building (the whole reason for wanting to test it first with Minikube) and see if that works.

Comment: It's great to hear that. If you have any problem during your "real" implementation, don't hesitate on posting a question.

Comment: If this was allowed by Ingress it would be so much more useful. Not being able to leave the host field out really limits testing.

Comment: I kept using the loop back address in the hosts file for mapping domain name. Your answer saved me!

Answer (score 53):

Here’s what worked for me:

1. minikube start
2. minikube addons enable ingress
3. minikube addons enable ingress-dns
4. Wait until you see the ingress-nginx-controller-XXXX is up and running using `Kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx`
5. Create an ingress using the K8s [example yaml file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/website/main/content/en/examples/service/networking/example-ingress.yaml)
6. Update the service section to point to the NodePort Service that you already created
7. Append
   `127.0.0.1 hello-world.info`
   to your /etc/hosts file on MacOS (**NOTE:
   Do NOT use the Minikube IP**)
8. Run `minikube tunnel` ( Keep the window open. After you entered the password there will be no more messages, and the cursor just blinks)
9. Hit the `hello-world.info` ( or whatever host you configured in the yaml file) in a browser and it should work

Comment: worked, but still curious why it doesn't work direct way.

Comment: Using 127.0.01 instead of the Minikube IP was exactly the point I missed! Thank you!

Comment: I too can confirm this is working! Thanks.

Comment: for m1 devices with docker driver , please use 127.0.0.1 <your dummy domain> in /etc/hosts.
My problem: I was using 192.168.49.2 <mydomain.com> and gave me hard time.

Comment: The proper solution is to use hyperv when you start minikube: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/hyperv/

Comment: Can someone explain the issue here? the above solution worked.

Comment: Im having internal service, how should i point to node port...

Comment: this worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the accepted answer, `minikube` now has a `tunnel` command which allows you generate external ip addresses for your services which can be accessed directly on your host machine without using the general `minikube ip`.

Run `minikube tunnel` in a separate terminal. This runs in the foreground as a daemon.
In a different terminal, execute your `kubectl apply -f <file_name>` command to deploy your desired service. It should generate an ip address for you that is routed directly to your service and available on port 80 on that address.

More here on the minikube documentation: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/tasks/loadbalancer/

Answer (score 5):

**I got Minikube on Windows 11 to work for me**

```
minikube start --vm-driver=hyperv
```

Install minikube Ingress Controller

```
minikube addons enable ingress
minikube addons enable ingress-dns
```

Deploy Helm Chart

```
helm install ...
```

Get Kubernetes IP Address

```
nslookup <host-found-in-ingress> $(minikube ip)
```

Add to etc/host

```
<minikube-ip> <domain-url>
```

Live!

```
curl <domain-url>
```

Comment: This is the proper way. Here is also the doc from minikube
https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/hyperv/

Comment: What i was missing is that ingress-dns addon, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your problem comes from how you start minkube. If you use just "minikube start" it will use your local docker desktop. This works fine for most scenario but for ingress, for some reason will not allow you to expose the external ip of ingress.

The proper way to achieve this is to start minikube with hyberv driver. There are 2 steps:

- Start windows powershell in Admin mode *important, and run commnad:

  `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All`
- If not already active you need to restart. You can also configure it manually from Windows Features.
- Start minikube with driver hyperv. Also requires to use Powershell in Admin. If you don't have admin rights, you probably can not do this

  `minikube start --driver=hyperv`
- Set the kyperv as default:

  `minikube config set driver hyperv`
- This last step requires a restart of cluster with delete, and the step is optional.

Complete documentation on how to setup minikube with hyperv:
https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/hyperv/

Sample how to setup ingress:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/

Answer (score 0):

### For Docker Desktop Driver (Default)

You should create a tunnel to your cluster with :

> minikube tunnel

Answer (score 0):

*You must determine which "docker mode" you are running. It can be "docker desktop" or "docker engine":*

- Check docker mode:

  `docker version | grep "Docker Engine"`

  Client: Docker Engine - Community

  `docker version | grep "Docker Engine"`

  Client: Docker Engine - Community

  Server: Docker Engine - Community

If you don't see the server, you are using Docker Desktop to run docker
The best solution would be to turn it off.

When you run `minikube start` you will get a warning if you are using Docker Desktop

**❗  For an improved experience it's recommended to use Docker Engine instead of Docker Desktop.
Docker Engine installation instructions: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/#server**

2. Enable ingress in minicube and load all preparatory data. I will use https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/ as a base:

   ```
    minikube addons enable ingress
    kubectl create deployment web --image=gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0
    kubectl expose deployment web --type=NodePort --port=8080
    kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/service/networking/example-ingress.yaml
    kubectl get ingress
   ```
3. Test inside and outside the minikube cluster
   3.1 Internal:

   ```
    minikube ssh
    curl -H "Host: hello-world.info" 127.0.0.1 #its work
   ```

   3.2 External Docker Engine

   ```
    curl -H "Host: hello-world.info" $(minikube ip) # only for docker engine
   ```

   3.3 External Docker Desktop

   ```
    ping $(minikube ip) # you won't see a response if it's docker desktop
    ssh -i $(minikube ssh-key) -p "$(docker port minikube 22/tcp | awk -F ':' '{print $2}')" docker@$(docker port minikube 22/tcp | awk -F ':' '{print $1}') #its work
   ```

   **make ssh tunnel**

   ```
    ssh -i $(minikube ssh-key) -p "$(docker port minikube 22/tcp | awk -F ':' '{print $2}')" docker@$(docker port minikube 22/tcp | awk -F ':' '{print $1}') -L 8008:localhost:80
    curl -H "Host: hello-world.info" 127.0.0.1:8008 #its work
   ```