# Minikube documentation on how to setup an ingress in Kubernetes doesn't work

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, minikube

I checked the previous question about this topic:
[Minikube with ingress example not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58561682/minikube-with-ingress-example-not-working)
But it doesn't solve my issue, since the solution doesn't work with newer version of **Kubernetes**. *Version 1.22*

- The command I used:

```
# Setup minikube
minikube start
minikube addons enable ingress

# Create the Deployment and Service
kubectl create deployment web --image=gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0;
kubectl expose deployment web --type=NodePort --port=8080;

# Create the Ingress
kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/service/networking/example-ingress.yaml;
```

Since I am using **Minikube** in local, I have to add the ip from `minikube ip` in the `etc/hosts`, which I did.

---

### CHECKING:

```
❯ kubectl get all
NAME                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/web-79d88c97d6-zfhgh   1/1     Running   0          24m

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP          25m
service/web          NodePort    10.97.138.67   <none>        8080:31460/TCP   24m

NAME                  READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/web   1/1     1            1           24m

NAME                             DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/web-79d88c97d6   1         1         1       24m
```

We have the **Pod**, the **Service**, the **Deployment** and the **RepicaSet**.✅

```
❯ kubectl get ingress
NAME              CLASS   HOSTS              ADDRESS        PORTS   AGE
example-ingress   nginx   hello-world.info   192.168.49.2   80      24m
```

The **Ingress** is okay, the address is indeed the **Minikube** IP. ✅

```
❯ cat /etc/hosts
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateHosts = false
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       DESKTOP-B4JM855.localdomain     DESKTOP-B4JM855

192.168.1.12    host.docker.internal
192.168.1.12    gateway.docker.internal
127.0.0.1       kubernetes.docker.internal
192.168.49.2    hello-world.info        # <----------- What we care about ✅ 

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Everything should be correct but, I can't curl to the **Ingress** with:

> curl http://hello-world.info

I do not know if using WSL is causing this issue, but it shouldn't be.

Comment: Try `minikube service web --url` Should work!!! You will get  an nice table on terminal and use the given link.

Comment: Yes, but I am trying to do is use the Ingress hello-world.info

Comment: Is that URL working ?.. Rest I will tell you,

Comment: It provides me with the url: http://127.0.0.1:45711 which indeed works

Comment: Trying with `minikube start --vm=true --driver=hyperkit` taking time to run ... hang tight.... Bottom line is K8 document is old and it need to be updated. Running with `hyperkit` drive.

Comment: I believe you are right, changing the driver made it works, by default minikube use docker driver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Well, I tried coupal of things but none of them worked out well with `docker driver`

As of now, there is a going issue with [ingress doesn't work on docker desktop kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/7686)

So you can't run ingress on local as of now with `docker Driver`. But you can try out this on AWS/IBM/GCP cloud and clear your task [link](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/deploying-aws-load-balancer-controller-ingress-eks-kai-jian-tan/).

> Alternatively, you can try with `hyperkit` `driver` like

```
minikube start --vm=true --driver=hyperkit
```

- Or Public Cloud (I tried and it worked) will be good choice to get it done fast.